# Recommended SharePoint and Office Web Apps 2013 topology

Tags: 2013, office-web-apps, intranet, internet

What is the recommended topology for deploy Office Web Applications with SharePoint 2013 supporting intranet and extranet scenarios?

How has this advanced since SharePoint 2007, 2010?

Comment: There are plenty of resources available to support these basic questions. Can you narrow them down to something a bit more specific?  For general overview please view the articles posted on Microsoft TechNet, as well as the blog posts by Wictor Wilen.

Answer (score 0):

Office Web Apps Server 2013 is its own product. You can review capacity planning guidelines for each (SharePoint and Office Web Apps) on TechNet. For a minimum topology, you want 2 Office Web Apps Servers and use load balancing to achieve high availability. There is a single PowerShell cmdlets that connects that to your SharePoint farm. Similarly, you can connect it to Exchange as well.

Answer (score -2):

Office Web Apps Server: Office Web Apps deployment simplified

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=38833